# Typo3 menu with font awesome icons

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I use typoscript (new to it) to handle the menu bar for my site and I want to use fontawesome icons next to the menu entries.

This is what the model look like:

[image]

This is how my menu look like:

[image]

Now, my typoscript subpart for menu looks this way:

```
    SUBNAV = HMENU
    SUBNAV {
                            entryLevel = 0
                            1 = TMENU
                            1 {
                                expAll = 1
                                collapse = active
                                noBlur = 1

                    # Definition per page
                    # NO: default formatting                                    
                                NO = 1
                                NO {
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li >|</li>
                                    stdWrap.wrap = <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>|</span> 
                                }

                    # ACT: User is on this or below this page
                    # Activate this state for this menu
                                ACT < .NO
                                ACT {
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
                                }
                                CUR < .ACT

                    # try to check if submenu to add a arrow icon                                   

                                IFSUB = 1
                                IFSUB{
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
                                    linkWrap = |<span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
                                    ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                                    stdWrap.wrap = <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>|</span>
                                }
                                ACTIFSUB = 1
                                ACTIFSUB < .ACT
                                ACTIFSUB.linkWrap = |<span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
                                ACTIFSUB.ATagBeforeWrap = 1

                                CURIFSUB = 1
                                CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB

                            }


                            2= TMENU
                            2 {
                                expAll = 1
                                collapse = active
                                noBlur = 1
                                wrap = <ul class="treeview-menu">|</ul>
                    # Definition per page
                    # NO: default formatting                                    
                                NO = 1
                                NO {
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li >|</li>
                                }

                    # ACT: User is on this or below this page
                    # Activate this state for this menu
                                ACT < .NO
                                ACT {
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
                                }
                                CUR < .ACT

                    # try to check if submenu to add a arrow icon                                   

                                IFSUB = 1
                                IFSUB{
                                    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li  >|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
                                    linkWrap = |<span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
                                    ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                                }
                                ACTIFSUB = 1
                                ACTIFSUB < .ACT
                                ACTIFSUB.linkWrap = |<span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
                                ACTIFSUB.ATagBeforeWrap = 1

                                CURIFSUB = 1
                                CURIFSUB < .ACTIFSUB

                            }


                            # Definition for pages on level 3 and lower                                                                                 
                            # Copy the definitions from level 2 
                                    3 < .2
                            #       3.wrap = <ul class="treeview-menu">|</ul>

                            # Copy the definitions from level 2
                                    4 < .2
                            #       4.wrap = <ul class="treeview-menu">|</ul>

                            # Copy the definitions from level 2
                                    5 < .2
                            #       5.wrap = <ul class="treeview-menu">|</ul>

                            # Copy the definitions from level 2
                                    6 < .2
                            #       6.wrap = <ul class="treeview-menu">|</ul>

                    }
```

Now, my problem is I don't know how to associate different icons (which I chose) with different menus (the ones in level 1). As you see in typoscript, I used a fa icon but is same for every menu entry (fa fa-plus). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Something is changed based on below sugestion but I'm not quite there yet. I've modified NO entry from typoscript:          NO {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         # stdWrap.wrap = <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>|</span> 
          stdWrap.wrap = <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>|</span> |*| <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>|</span>
         }, but this works only for items without submenus. Same code under IFSUB section does not work... So, still trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite number of menu items you can replace your code:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li>|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
```

With:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first icon1">|</li>|*|<li class="icon2">|</li>|*|<li class="icon3">|</li>|*|<li class="icon4">|</li>|*|<li class="last iconN">|</li>
```

To control the display of each list item.